# Qual o tempo de vida do decorator lru_cache?

Tags: python, cache

Estou desenvolvendo um script em Python que necessita memorizar as informações (possivelmente um cache) de instâncias anteriores e acabei encontrando o decorator `@functools.lru_cache`, porém fiquei com dúvidas ao [ler a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Este decorator memoriza informações apenas até o término da instância ou memoriza as informações após o término da instância também?

Caso resposta negativa, pode dar sugestões de como posso fazer isso, ou um caminho que possa seguir para chegar até isso?

Comment: Se você precisa de um cache que viva mesmo após o reinício da aplicação, considere o Redis: https://redis.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há especificação para o tempo de vida, só para o tamanho, o `@functools.lru_cache` funciona como dicionário, então enquanto a sua aplicação e função com o decorador estiverem lá o recurso existirá, por isso é recomendado usar o `maxsize=` com um tamanho não muito grande (padrão é 128), para evitar o uso descontrolado, se definir `maxsize=None` o recurso LRU será desabilitado e o cache poderá crescer sem limites, o que pode causar sérios problemas.

Note que se usar `typed=true`, os argumentos da função de diferentes tipos serão armazenados em cache separadamente, exemplo: `foobar(3)` e `foobar(3.0)` serão tratados como chamadas distintas com resultados distintos, o que irá necessitar de mais recursos, então é bom avaliar o que é necessário.

Existe também o método `.clear_cache`, com ele em qualquer momento você poderá invalidar o cache de uma função, exemplo:

```
@lru_cache
def foobar():
   return ..algoaqui..

foobar() # retorna o resultado
foobar() # retorna o mesmo resultado, possivelmente em cache

# descarta o cache existente para "foobar()"
foobar.clear_cache()
```

No algoritimo LRU usado por esse decorador, irá **descartar** os itens menos usados recentemente primeiro.